# How to add Objects in an ArrayList with an abstract Class

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add Card objects into an ArrayList of Cards in order to create a Deck of Cards. In order to do that I looped through the suits and the values of the cards and attempted to add Card objects. I am getting an error that I cannot instantiate the type Card.

This is my Card Class:

```
public abstract class Card
{
public static final String FACES[] = {"ZERO","ACE","TWO","THREE","FOUR",
        "FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN","JACK","QUEEN","KING"};
private String suit;
private int number;

//constructors
public Card(){
    
   }

public Card ( int num, String type) {
    
    number = num; 
    suit = type;
    
    }




// modifiers




//accessors

public String getSuit() {
    return suit; 
   }


public int getNumber() {
    return number; 
    }




public abstract int getValue();

public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (getNumber()==((Card) obj).getNumber()) {
        
        return true;
    }
    
    
    return false;
}

//toString
public String toString () {
int var = getNumber(); 
return FACES[var] + " of " + getSuit() + " | Value " + getValue();

}
```

}

This is my Deck Class:

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Collections;

   public class Deck
  {
    public static final int NUMFACES = 13;
     public static final int NUMSUITS = 4;
    public static final int NUMCARDS = 52;

 public static final String SUITS[] = {"CLUBS","SPADES","DIAMONDS","HEARTS"};

 private int topCardIndex;
 private ArrayList<Card> stackOfCards;

public Deck ()
{
    
    
    
    
    //initialize data - stackOfCards - topCardIndex
    
    topCardIndex = 0; 
    
    
    for (int i=0;i<NUMSUITS;i++){
        for( int j=0; j<NUMFACES; j++) {
            stackOfCards.add(new Card(j,SUITS[i]));
        }
    }//loop through suits
        //loop through faces
            //add in a new card
    
}

 //modifiers
    public void shuffle ()
  {
    //shuffle the deck
    //reset variables as needed
   }

//accessors
     public int  size ()
   {
    return 0;
  }

public int numCardsLeft()
{
    return stackOfCards.size();
    
}

public Card nextCard()
{
    return stackOfCards.get(topCardIndex--);
}

public String toString()
{
    return stackOfCards + "   topCardIndex = " + topCardIndex;
}
```

}

Comment: abstract class cannot be instantiated. Please read about abstract classes.

Comment: You cannot instantiate an instance of an abstract class.  Is there a reason you have defined `Card` as abstract?

Comment: maybe the [Abstract Methods and Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) section of 
[The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) from Oracle can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having the type of a List to an abstract class you can add any extention of that abstract class to that list. For example, if you would have an abstract class `Car` and two other classes: `FooCar` and `BarCar` extends that class you are allowed to add both an instance of `FooCar` and `BarCar` to that list.

In your implementation of card however there is no point in it being abstract,  in fact it shouldn't be abstract as you are trying to instantiate it.

For more information about abstraction I suggest to check out: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_abstract.asp, it provides a easy to follow guide on how to use abstraction and what it is. You can also use the official documentation for more information https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html